# VUETIFY - How to pass slot to nested select component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slot

I'm using last version of `vuetify` and trying to figure out how to make slots work. Documentation about select may be find [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects)

**VSelectWithValidation**

```
<v-select v-model="innerValue" :error-messages="errors" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
      {{ data.item.name }}
  </template>
   <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
      {{ data.item.name }} - {{ data.item.description }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

**TestComponent**

```
<VSelectWithValidation
    rules="required"
    :items="items"
    v-model="select"
    label="Select">
    // I WOULD LIKE SLOTS TO BE AT THIS LEVEL
</VSelectWithValidation>
```

Basically, I would like the slots to be customized so I need to move them out of the `VSelectWithValidation` component to be set on the `TestComponent`

I tried different variations with no success.

https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-u11fd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## VSelectWithValidation

You need to create slot inside your template slot item and bind scope data to able to use from other component ..

```
<template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
   <slot name="item" v-bind="data"></slot>
</template>
```

## TestComponent

You can access that slot by writing ***v-slot:YourSlotName="hereIsBindData"***

```
<template v-slot:item="data">
    {{ data.item.name }} // you can code here whatever you like
</template>
```

Comment: Any way to make it optional?  Now every select for which I do not pass a slot are broken.

Comment: how about adding new prop called isSlot(boolean) to check will current select use slot or not with `v-if="isSlot"` ...

Comment: @LéoCoco, how about `v-if="$slots.item"` for checking slot named "item"?